# Zipping .htaccess files

Tags: php, zip

I zip some files on the server with kohanaphp and the archive module, all works fine but the zipped .htaccess files are gone after unzipping.
Thanx for help.

Answer (score 5):

No, they're just hidden. Use `ls -A`.